# Defaulting to Latest Record when between statement condition is not satisfied?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, apache-spark-sql

I've got 2 tables. Sales and Product rates.

Sales looks like:

| Id | SurogateKey | TransactionDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 343 | 2020-09-01T00:00:00 |
| 2 | 3 | 2020-08-01T00:00:00 |
| 3 | 3 | 2020-10-01T00:00:00 |
| 4 | 96 | 2020-09-01T00:00:00 |
| 5 | 343 | 2020-01-01T00:00:00 |

Product Rates:

| Id | Rate | StartDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 343 | 95.2 | 2020-09-01T00:00:00 |
| 3 | 87.2 | 2020-08-01T00:00:00 |
| 3 | 3 | **2020-09-01T00:00:00** |
| 3 | 96 | 2020-09-01T00:00:00 |
| 343 | 343 | 2020-01-01T00:00:00 |

What I want to know is the rate for a given sale:

1. that applied for that StartDate to end of the month
2. In the scenario where no StartDate is present to take the most recent and use that.

Here's my logic for the scenario 1:

```
select *
from sales as s
left join producct rate as pr 
    on s.SurogateKey = pr.Id
    and s.TransactionDate between pr.StartDate and eomonth(pr.StartDate)
```

However, how would I get the latest record for those that have no StartDate in that given month.

| Id | SurogateKey | TransactionDate | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 343 | 2020-09-01T00:00:00 | 95.2 |
| 2 | 3 | 2020-08-01T00:00:00 | 87.2 |
| ** 3** | 3 | **2020-10-01T00:00:00** | **3** |
| 4 | 96 | 2020-09-01T00:00:00 | NULL |
| 5 | 343 | 2020-01-01T00:00:00 | 343 |

I feel it is something like:

```
select *
from sales as s 
left join producct rate as pr 
    on s.SurogateKey = pr.Id
    and (
        s.TransactionDate between pr.StartDate and eomonth(pr.StartDate)
        or (
            s.TransactionDate not between pr.StartDate and eomonth(pr.StartDate) 
            and S.TransactionDate > pr.StartDate
        )
    )
```

What am I doing wrong?

DBFIDDLE

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dgFkhVhs7KjLgu5H2NS8Fm/0

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPeay.png

Comment: My bad! I get my different sql syntaxes mixed up sometimes. It would be like EOMMONTH In TSQL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) . I want to understand how to solve this in any sql variant conceptually then I'll apply it in my domain specific SQL.

Comment: Does your ProductRate table not have a unique key?

Comment: I added a DB fiddle. Product rate its effectively a slowly changing dimension. And no 96 can be missing thats fine, in that scenario we should set the product rate as null

Comment: Good point! Sorry I didn't realise I made that mistake. Fixed it

Comment: I guess my only thoughts are to make a CTE perhaps with a latest flag and use it in the or condition when NOT Between but that would lead to duplicates from the join.

Answer (score 1):

The following does what you desire. Using an `outer apply` to choose the correct `ProductRate` to join on. And then using a prioritised `order by` to first select the rate from within the window, and if not then just the most recent.

I would normally use a `left join` with a query to select the correct row to join on, but as you, unusually, don't appear to have a unique key on your `ProductRate` table, the join option doesn't work.

```
declare @Sale table (id int, SurogateKey int, TransactionDate datetime);

insert into @Sale (Id, SurogateKey, TransactionDate)
values
(1,343,'2020-09-01T00:00:00'),
(2,3,'2020-08-01T00:00:00'),
(3,3,'2020-10-01T00:00:00'),
(4,96,'2020-09-01T00:00:00'),
(5,343,'2020-01-01T00:00:00');

declare @ProductRate table (id int, Rate decimal(9,2), StartDate datetime);

insert into @ProductRate (id, Rate, StartDate)
values
(343,95.2,'2020-09-01T00:00:00'),
(3,87.2,'2020-08-01T00:00:00'),
(3,3,'2020-09-01T00:00:00'),
(3,96,'2020-09-01T00:00:00'),
(343,343,'2020-01-01T00:00:00');

select S.id, S.SurogateKey, S.TransactionDate, PR1.Rate, PR1.StartDate
from @Sale S
outer apply (
    select top 1 Rate, StartDate
    from @ProductRate PR
    where PR.id = S.SurogateKey
    order by case when S.TransactionDate >= PR.StartDate and S.TransactionDate < dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(PR.StartDate)) then 1 else 0 end desc
        , PR.StartDate desc
) PR1 (Rate, StartDate);
```

Returns:

| id | SurogateKey | TransactionDate | Rate | StartDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 343 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 95.20 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 3 | 2020-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 87.20 | 2020-08-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 3 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 3.00 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 96 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | 343 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 343.00 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 |

Note: I'm not a fan of `between`, its behaviour is unintuitive (IMO), and doesn't work as expected when using `datetime` instead of `date`. I prefer a manually constructed window as shown.